# Hartshorne II.3.22c following the hint

Tags: algebraic-geometry, dimension-theory-algebra, fibre-product

I know this exercise can be solved in several ways, such as Ravi Vakil's proof or [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2360128/hartshorne-exercise-ii-3-22-c-dimension-of-fibers), but I'd like to try to follow the given hint if possible.

The exercise says the following:

> Let $f:X→Y$ be a dominant morphism of integral schemes of finite type over a field $k$. Show there is an open dense subset $U⊆X$ s.t. $\dim U_y=\dim X−\dim Y$ for all $y$ in the image of $U$.
>
> Hint: First reduce to the case where $X$ and $Y$ are affine, say $X=SpecA$ and $Y=SpecB$. Then $A$ is a finitely generated $B$-algebra. Take $t_1,\dots,t_e∈A$ which form a transcendence base of $K(X)$ over $K(Y)$, and let $X_1=SpecB[t_1,...,t_e]$. Then $X_1$ is isomorphic to affine $e$-space over $Y$, and the morphism $X→X_1$ is generically finite. Now use (Ex. 3.7) above.

I've done most of the process, so I'll go directly to the place I'm stuck. Let $g:X\to X_1$ the morphism of the hint, which I've proved that is dominant, generically finite and of finite type.

By Ex II.3.7 there exists an open dense subset $U_1\subseteq X_1$ such that, takin $U=g^{-1}(U_1)$, the induced morphism $g|_U:U→U_1$ is finite. I claim that $U⊆X$ is the desired set. Certainly it is a dense open set, since $X$ integral implies $X$ is irreducible (Proposition 3.1) and $U$ is nonempty, so that it is automatically dense. Thus, we need only check that $y∈f(U)$ implies $\dim U_y=e$.

I think using (b) I can show that $\dim U_y\geq e$, by I don't know how to proof the other inequality. In addition I haven't (at least explicitily) used that $X_1$ is an affine $e$-space, so that might be the key.

Part (b), under the same hypothesis as (c)

> Let $e=\dim X-\dim Y$. For any point $y\in f(X)$, show that every irreducible component of the fibre $X_y$ has dimension $\geq e$.

Comment: Please include the statement of the exercise in your post. Posts should be *self contained*. Thank you!

Comment: It should follow from finiteness+that $X_1$ is affine space over $Y$. Roughly speaking, we should have that the fiber in $U_1$ is $e$ dimensional, since $X_1$ is affine $e$-space, and then since $U\to U_1$ is finite, the fiber in $U$ will be at most $e$-dimensional, since if $f:X\to Y$ is integral, then $\dim Y\ge \dim X$. See [Stacks](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01WG).

Comment: Thank you @jgon Perhaps you want to write an answer

Comment: By the way @jgon I never said $f$ was integral, $X$ and $Y$ are integral schemes, does that somehow imply  that $f$ must be integral?

Comment: @Javi finite implies integral, so $g$ restricted to $U$ is integral. $f$ is not integral, I phrased the result I was trying to quote poorly in my prior comment by reusing your variables thoughtlessly. My bad.