# Dimension of Zariski closure of the image of an algebraic map

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, dimension-theory-analysis

Let $\phi: \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be a polynomial map with rational coefficients. Let $M$ be the Zariski closure of the image of $\phi$ (in the complex space $\mathbb{C}^n$). Then the following holds

$$
\dim(M) = \dim(\mathbb{R}^m) - \dim(\phi^{-1}(\phi(p)))
$$
where $p$ is a generic point in $\mathbb{R}^m$ (generic means its coordinates are algebraic independent over the rational field $Q$).

My question is: why is this true? This seems to be well-known as it is given without a reference in a paper I read. Does anyone know a reference of this equality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expose 8 in Cartan and Chevalley, *Geometrie Algebrique*, Seminar Cartan-Chevalley, Secretariat Math., Paris, (1955/56) is the original reference, though this might not be the best to learn from (it is in French and uses early language).

This is also available as Hartshorne's exercise II.3.22 (one solution on MSE [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2360128/hartshorne-exercise-ii-3-22-c-dimension-of-fibers)) or can be found in section 11.4 of Vakil's [Foundations of Algebraic Geometry](http://math.stanford.edu/%7Evakil/216blog/FOAGnov1817public.pdf).

(PS: your definition of a generic point is incorrect. What you want to interpret this statement as is that all $p$ except possibly those in some proper closed subset work. A counterexample to what you've written is $\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^2$ by $(x,y)\mapsto (x-x_0,(x-x_0)y)$: take $x_0$ and $y_0$ to be such that $\Bbb Q(x_0,y_0)$ is of transcendence degree 2 over $\Bbb Q$, then $\dim \varphi^{-1}(\varphi((x_0,y_0)))=1$ since $\varphi^{-1}(\varphi((x_0,y_0)))$ is $\{(x_0,y)\mid y\in\Bbb R\}$. But $M$ has dimension two.)

Comment: But the example you gave is not algebraic right?  By saying algebraic map, I mean each component of the map $\phi$ is a polynomial over Q.

Comment: That's, like, at most the fourth-most common use of that term. The above is the material you asked for a reference for, and I hope you find it helpful. Good day.

Comment: Actually, your definition should probably pop out after considering the map on affine space over $\Bbb Q$ given by the same polynomials and then noting that the closed set where the condition fails is defined over the rationals plus the fact that the base extension of this set to the reals is also the locus where the condition fails in that case. Still, though, please define your terms next time.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the definition to polynomial map over rationals, then my definition of generic point should be correct, right?

Comment: "Correct" is a loaded word. I would not choose to characterize things the way you have been doing. Here is why: picking the right formalization of the concept of a generic point was one of the central challenges for the entire field of algebraic geometry from about 1900-1960. Your definition is really close to one of the attempts that didn't quite make it, and there's an opportunity for confusion here. I would prefer to say that the result is true for a *general* $p$ and since your map is defined over $\Bbb Q$, the locus where the claim fails is a proper closed subset defined over $\Bbb Q$...

Comment: and therefore for any point $p$ where the dimension formula fails, the coordinates cannot all be algebraically independent over $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: I see, Thanks for the clarification. Based on the MSE solution, it seems this formula is also true for Zariski closure over the reals instead of complex numbers?